# How do you get the Premium Collectible Pack in multiplayer?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've seen people talk about a Premium Collectible Pack in multiplayer. The mass effect wiki shows it as this:

Premium Collectible Pack (Free, single-use) - A special bonus for dedicated Mass Effect fans.

But does anyone know how to get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Premium Collectible Pack" comes with the purchase of action figure packs, as shown [here](http://biowarestore.com/mass-effect/mass-effect-accessories/series-2-action-figure-four-pack).

The [linked page](http://biowarestore.com/mass-effect/mass-effect-accessories/series-2-action-figure-four-pack) describes the bonus in the following text:

> These products contain a code that can be redeemed for bonus content for Mass Effect 3 multi-player . The pack could include character boosters, weapons, weapon modifications and upgrades to make your multi-player squad stronger.

This translates to the "special bonus for dedicated Mass Effect fans" you referred to in your question. It is misleading to have the word "free" included in any sort of description of this pack as you're required to spend a substantial amount to get the figures and code.

Referenced product:
[image]